# Using custom methods with Django SimpleListFilter

Tags: django, function, django-models, filter, admin

In essence, my problem is that the following set-up is returning the entire queryset in the admin page regardless of what I filter for.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Booking(models.model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ....

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.reference

class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    ...

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name  

    def total_bookings(self):
        return len(self.booking_set.all())

    def bookings0(self):
        if self.total_bookings() == 0:
            return True

    def bookings1(self):
        if self.total_bookings() == 1:
            return True

    def bookings2(self):
        if self.total_bookings() == 2:
            return True

    def bookings3plus(self):
        if self.total_bookings() > 2:
            return True

...
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from clakes.models import Client, Booking ...

class BookingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

class NumBookingListFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Number of Bookings')
    parameter_name = 'numofbooks'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('no', _('No Bookings')),
            ('1', _('One')),
            ('2', _('Two')),
            ('3plus', _('Three or more')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 'no':
            return [x for x in queryset if x.bookings0()]
        if self.value() == '1':
            return [x for x in queryset if x.bookings1()]
        if self.value() == '2':
            return [x for x in queryset if x.bookings2()]
        if self.value() == '3plus':
            return [x for x in queryset if x.bookings3plus()]

class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'total_bookings', ...)
    search_fields = ['name']
    list_filter = (NumBookingListFilter,)
    ...

...
admin.site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
admin.site.register(Booking, BookingAdmin)
```

Can someone please explain to me where I have gone wrong. The filter appears on the 'Client' admin page as expected, but when one option is selected the filter does not work - the url changes to http:.../client/?e=1 but no filtering has occurred as it should. My list comprehension works in shell - e.g. [x for x in queryset if x.bookings1()] returns a correct list of clients.

I would happily consider a different approach using managers, or whatever. Whoever is kind enough to answer, please do not just point me at documentation as I have spent hours now reading and re-reading it, and so if I have missed the point it is due to a lack of understanding rather than effort.

Comment: For dynamically typed language like python using same name for a function as well as a parameter is a bad idea.
Both the queryset function's return value and the queryset parameter are iterables.

Comment: Where have I done this? - I think I have only used distinct names, albeit sometimes similar, eg the class is Booking, whereas functions are total_bookings, bookings0, bookings1 etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, there are probably neater ways of going about the entire thing, but the following worked for me:

admin.py

```
if self.value() == 'no':
        l = [x.id for x in queryset if x.bookings0()]
        return queryset.filter(pk__in=l)
if self.value() == '1':
        l = [x.id for x in queryset if x.bookings1()]
        return queryset.filter(pk__in=l)
...etc...
```

I hope this helps someone at some point.